# How set %Y-%m conditon to get date < %Y-%n in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue, I want to show all the dates whose month is below February, for example:
call data with the where parameter (2021-02-25) it will call all data under February, regardless of the date and year, because the data I need is data under February 2021

I've tried:

```
->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(tanggal_inv,'%Y-%m'))"), "<", (string)date("Y-m", strtotime('2021-02-25')))
```

but I also get data whose date is in February too, how do I get data for the month under February 2021 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want all the data where the date is less than 2021-02-01?

Comment: $last_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['date']));
                    ->whereDate('tanggal_inv', '<=', $last_date);

Comment: yes Mr.Will Walsh

Comment: When you say you ge tdata for Feb too do you mean for the entire month or is it just specific dates that you get back and you don't expect them to?

Comment: @apokryfos only data under February 2021, and I don't want to display data for February 2021, only under February 2021

Comment: No I'm asking what Feb data you get when you run this query. What Feb dates. I'm not asking what you want to get. For example are you getting data for Feb 20th or is it just e.g. Feb 1st ?

Answer (score 0):

This should worK?

```
->whereDate('tanggal_inv', '<', date('2021-02-25'));
```

Comment: btw I'm using laravel version 8, does that have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all dates before Feb-2021 then

```
datefield < '2021-02-01'  // geta all records where date before 1st Feb - 2021
```

in your case, it's

```
tanggal_inv < '2021-02-01'
```

Comment: I don't want to get data that is in February, only under February 2021

Comment: Above syntax will do the same.

Comment: Idk why, but I still got data Feb 2021, how to get that only under Feb 2021 ?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all data where the date is less than '2021-02-01' you can use the following.

```
$date = "2021-02-25";
Model::whereMonth('coulmn', '<', Carbon::parse($date)->format('m'))
    ->whereYear('column', '=', Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->whereDate('tanggal_inv', '<', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['date']));
```

Hope fully it will help to you.

Comment: I still got the February 2021 with that code

Comment: only got it February 2021 data?

Comment: only under February 2021, without data for February 2021